# Can one always use complex numbers for finding the coefficients of a partial fraction decomposition?

Tags: complex-numbers, partial-fractions

I have following term, which I would like to decompose into partial fractions:

$ \frac{1}{x^2(1+x^2)} \overset{!}{=} \frac{Ax+B}{1+x^2} +  \frac{C}{x} + \frac{D}{x^2}$

Multiplying everything out gives:

$ 1 = (Ax+B)x^2+Cx(1+x^2)+D(1+x^2)$

By plugging in arbitrary values for x such as 0, 1, 2, or 3, it leads to a system of equations that yields the correct coefficients:

$A=C=0, \qquad B=-1, \qquad D = 1$

However, I could have reached this solution much faster by making use of complex numbers, such as plugging in 0, i, -i, and 1. But in my problem, x is defined to be a real number.

My question: Is it always legitimate to substitute complex numbers when finding partial fraction decompositions, or are there some cases where you run into problems?

Comment: Yes, this is always the case. You can prove that the set $\{ x^i\}_{i=0}^{\infty} \cup  \{ 1/(x-b)^k: a\in \mathbf{C}, k \in \mathbf{Z}_{>0} \}$ forms a $\mathbf{C}$-basis of $\mathbf{C}(x)$ (field of rational functions with complex coefficients).

Comment: As a side note, you know in this example that $A$ and $C$ must be zero because it is equivalent to decomposing $\frac{1}{u(1+u)}$ where $u=x^2$